# Error in :0:0 caused by: Response with status: 0 for URL: null Angular 2.0 Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I am new to Angular 2.0 and I am trying to build a sample app using `@angular\cli`.

So I use `ng serve --open` to serve the application in `localhost:4200`.

Now, I have a service called `example.service.ts` and the code looks like :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable() //Decorator

export class ExampleService {
    private _url : string = "file:///Users/chiranjib/Documents/Angular%202%20Tutorial/ninja-app/apidata/employeedata.json";
    constructor(private _http : Http){}
    getEmployees(){
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((response : Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

The file `employeedata.json` resides in `apidata` folder within local.

In my `component` I do:

```
this._exampleService.getEmployees().subscribe((resEmployeeData) => this.employees = resEmployeeData);
```

But it shows the error :

[image]

Even in **firefox** the error remains.

If do,

```
private _url : string = "apidata/employeedata.json";
```

The error shows:

[image]

How to solve the error and get my app working?

Comment: First image is a cors issue, normally cause app is in two different domains, and the second is a not found, meaning that resource cant be found.

Comment: Please include errors as text, not images.

Comment: are you having the json file in the application folder? what is the app-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> XMLHttpRequest can not load `file://...`. Cross Origin Requests are only supported for protocol schemes http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Means that the browser refused to load the JSON from a `file://` url for security reasons. That makes sense, because it would be a privacy nightmare if website were allowed to read files on user's hard drives.

Specifically, any request to a URL of a different [origin](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#section-origin) needs a [special  permission](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) of the requested URL, and no such permission is given for `file://` URLs.

To fix this, you need to make the JSON available over HTTP (ideally from the same host and port, so it's on the same origin). The easiest way to accomplish this in angular CLI is to put it into the `src/assets` folder, and load it from `/assets/employeedata.json`.

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful explanation and resolution.